# Why does the app crash on iPad Air because of Metal API

Tags: ios, metal, unreal-engine4

my iOS app is currently being rejected because of crashing on the iPad Air device according to my apple app Reviewer. I am desperate and don't know how to fix that issue. They only send me the crashlog and say that it works on other devices. I have no iPad air to test on. If someone owns an iPad air and would like to get the public testflight link please just contact. Here is the log with the threat that Always crashes the app:

I tried everything I can there is Nothing online to find. I just hope someone understands log text.

```
Thread 55 name:  Dispatch queue: com.Metal.CompletionQueueDispatch
Thread 55 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf05f104 0x1bf03c000 + 143620
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001bf0db020 0x1bf0d9000 + 8224
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001befb6d78 0x1bef5f000 + 359800
3   IOSEZY                          0x00000001011d2b24 0x100798000 + 10726180
4   IOSEZY                          0x00000001012c2910 0x100798000 + 11708688
5   IOSEZY                          0x0000000101285818 0x100798000 + 11458584
6   IOSEZY                          0x000000010113cbb0 0x100798000 + 10111920
7   IOSEZY                          0x0000000101153430 0x100798000 + 10204208
8   IOSEZY                          0x000000010113c160 0x100798000 + 10109280
9   IOSEZY                          0x000000010113c030 0x100798000 + 10108976
10  IOSEZY                          0x000000010113cc5c 0x100798000 + 10112092
11  IOSEZY                          0x0000000100c01aec 0x100798000 + 4627180
12  Metal                           0x00000001c167dc58 0x1c1618000 + 416856
13  Metal                           0x00000001c167f1f4 0x1c1618000 + 422388
14  Metal                           0x00000001c16285e0 0x1c1618000 + 67040
15  Metal                           0x00000001c1683bd0 0x1c1618000 + 441296
16  Metal                           0x00000001c1651350 0x1c1618000 + 234320
17  IOAccelerator                   0x00000001c160f164 0x1c160c000 + 12644
18  IOKit                           0x00000001bf728b24 0x1bf723000 + 23332
19  IOKit                           0x00000001bf728bb4 0x1bf723000 + 23476
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beebab58 0x1beea1000 + 105304
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001bef02484 0x1beea1000 + 398468
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beea582c 0x1beea1000 + 18476
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beeb5b9c 0x1beea1000 + 84892
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beea9a9c 0x1beea1000 + 35484
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beeaa718 0x1beea1000 + 38680
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001beeb2eb8 0x1beea1000 + 73400
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001bf0e50dc 0x1bf0d9000 + 49372
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001bf0e7cec 0x1bf0d9000 + 60652
```

Comment: Post a symbolicated crash report.

Comment: dear mag_zbc, I would really like to but This app was build on a Windows machine with remote build on a mac. That is how unreal engine 4 does it. I do not know how to get more out of it. As I have read online you Need a .dsym file to read the log. I only have the Option in unreal engine to check the mark whcih states "generate dsym files for Debugging" and "generate dsym bundle for third Party crash tools". I was only able to send the app to apple as a shipping build withcout debug files. I do not own an iPad Air to attach it and get the logs. Sorry but still thank you for your attention

Comment: The one thing that might help narrow it down is that the crash itself isn't in Metal. What's happening is that a command buffer is completing, its completion handler is being invoked on a background thread, and your app is doing...something invalid in response. The most common cause of such a crash is use-after-free, but it's going to be extremely hard to come to a more definite conclusion without more information.

Comment: thank you warrenm. I don't know how familiar you are with UE4 but it seems to me that I will Need to shift the Project to the newest unreal engine Version. If it's a bug, it's a horrible one. But it seems irrational because my App's Version 1.0 (which was approved by apple and is available in the app store) was build using iOS sdk11 and UE4.18.3.   Now I've shifted to apples SDK 12 and needed to upgrade to UE4.20.1. A still thank you I'm ver pi**ed off. I can't even simply exclude iPads ause they already told me that the app Needs to run on both iPad and iPhone, even if it was ment iPhone only

Comment: Indeed. I'm very sympathetic to your situation. Obscure crashes in large libraries that only happen on hardware you don't have are a trifecta of misery :-/

Comment: iPad Air is an A7 device, the oldest that supports the metal API. Perhaps you're using features that are unavailable on older devices? Perhaps you would be able to repro on similar devices (iPhone5S, iPadMini2/3). Perhaps you exceed limits for "iOS GPU family 1" devices? See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/HardwareGPUInformation/HardwareGPUInformation.html